# Move numbers in directions in multidimensional array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2048

I am programming a 2048 clone (a simple one) and the method I am working on is sliding the numbers in the multidimensional array as far as posible in the specified direction. I have this code for sliding left but I can't figure out how to adapt it to slide up, down and right.

```
public void moveLeft(int[][] grid)
{
    int [][] copy = grid;
    for(int x = 0; x < copy.length; x++){
        int[] row = new int[4];
        for(int y = 0; y < copy[x].length; y++){

            if (copy[x][y] != 0)
            {
                int temp = 0;
                while(row[temp] != 0) {
                    temp++;
                }
                row[temp] = copy[x][y];
            }

        }
        copy[x] = row;
    }
    grid = copy;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it supposed to say `moveUp(int[][] grid)`? Cause you are not using `matriz` and `grid` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I am writing in spanish and I forgot to translate that. Edited.

Comment: Keep in mind that arrays are objects and not primitive values. `copy` is not actually a copy. It is another reference that points to the same object. If you want to copy it, you would have to use `clone()` or do it manually in two for-loops.

Comment: Oh, ok, I made the copy for later on to check to see if the board has changed. Ignore that. The method is working perfectly to slide left but what I want is to be able to slide in other directions as well and I cannot figure out how. Thanks.

Comment: Understanding your code is not easy. It is not really straight forward, and you have no comments explaining what you are doing. Furthermore, the method is called `moveUp()` but you are using it to move left?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments consider how you are going to use the `copy` variable and `clone()`

The solution is based on your code. I changed it a little so you can achieve the addition when same number (2,4,8 etc) are next to each other:

```
public void moveLeft(int[][] grid){
    int [][] copy = grid.clone();
    for(int x = 0; x < copy.length; x++){
        int[] row = new int[4];
        for(int y = 0; y < copy[x].length; y++){
            if (copy[x][y] != 0){
                int temp = 0;
                while(row[temp] != 0) {
                    temp++;
                }
                row[temp] = copy[x][y];
            }
        }
        for(int k=0; k<row.length-1; k++){
            if(row[k] == row[k+1]){
                row[k] = row[k]+row[k+1];
                row[k+1] = 0;
            }
        }
        copy[x] = row;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < copy.length; x++){
        int[] row = new int[4];
        for(int y = 0; y < copy[x].length; y++){
            if (copy[x][y] != 0){
                int temp = 0;
                while(row[temp] != 0) {
                    temp++;
                }
                row[temp] = copy[x][y];
            }
        }
        copy[x] = row;
    }
    grid = copy;
}
```

If you run it:

```
int[][] b = {{0, 2, 0, 2},{2, 2, 0, 8},{4, 4, 4, 2},{4, 2, 4, 2}};
moveLeft(b);
```

You get the following:

```
4 0 0 0 
4 8 0 0 
8 4 2 0 
4 2 4 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a separate method for adding and then I move again, which is basically what your method does. I wanted to be able to move right, up and down too. What I did in the end was rotate the array, the move left, then rotate again to the original position.

Comment: @Paw I would keep the method as it is. In the case that you want to move elements down, you have to rotate the array to the right. So, if first column will become first row, for example in the array b I posted above the column [0, 2, 4, 4] has to become first row and the same for rest date of the array. After that you run moveLeft(b); and then rotate the array back to its previous state. The same thing you have to do for "moveRight(b)" (rotate twice, run moveLeft) and for "moveUp(b)" (rotate 3 times, run moveLeft).